# RealmRecyclerViewAdapter inside NestedScrollView doesn't show it's content on the first launch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I've encountered a problem with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter while developing a layout with a following hierarchy:

```
>CoordinatorLayout
-->NestedScrollView 
----> ConstraintLayout 
------> RecyclerView
```

The problem is that on first launch RecyclerView doesn't show its children after data is inserted into Realm.

My **fragment_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainLogo"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="184dp"
                android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabDots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pager"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabPadding="2dp"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="2dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGuideOrder"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="@style/BtnBlock.Left"
                android:text="@string/btn_guide_order"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnGuidePay"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGuidePay"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="@style/BtnBlock.Right"
                android:text="@string/btn_guide_pay"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnGuideOrder"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_product"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_product"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_product"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_product"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGuideOrder"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_product"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Setting up RecyclerView:

```
private fun setupRecycler() {
    fetchProducts(RetrofitManager.homeCategoryId)
    val products = realm.where(Product::class.java).findAll()
    rvAdapter = RealmProductAdapter(products)

    recycler.apply {
        adapter = rvAdapter
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }
}
```

Fetching data:

```
private fun fetchProducts(categoryId: Int) {
    val mContext = context ?: return
    showProgress()

    val disposable = RetrofitManager.createService(mContext, IctService::class.java)
            .getCategoryProducts(authHeader(), categoryId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({

                Log.d(_tag, "products, on Next")

                realm.executeTransaction { _ ->
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(it)
                }

                hideProgress()
            }, { error ->
                Log.e(_tag, "error: $error, ${error.stackTrace}")

                showErrorDialog { fetchProducts(categoryId) }
                hideProgress()
            })
    compositeDisposable?.add(disposable)
}
```

What I've tried so far?

1. I've checked that RealmRecyclerViewAdapter calls notifyItemRangeInserted internally when data is inserted into realm, but it doesn't update the layout. Only Calling notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter manually when ChangeListener is triggered forces Recycler to show it's content.

   ```
   products.addChangeListener { results, changeSet ->
       Log.d(_tag, "setupRecycler, realmChangeListener, results: $results, set: $changeSet")
       rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
   ```
2. Replacing ConstraintLayout with another one (LinearLayout) doesn't solve the issue. But if I put RecyclerView inside CoordinatorLayout directly - it shows it's children immediately after data is inserted into Realm. So the problem is related to RecyclerView being children of NestedScrollView only.

Comment: Maybe if you remove `setHasFixedSize(true)` it'll work

Comment: Yes, you're right! It's just a bit strange behaviour, imho.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You're my hero.